# undeclared method

Tags: java

Aca deje 2 pedacitos de un codigo, en el boolean de abajo cuando pongo

> `fechaPrestamo.obtenerPlazoDev()` me dice **undeclared method** pero esta declarado literalmente arriba

**Aclaracion:** Fecha y Libro vienen de otras clases, esta es la clase Prestamo y el error esta en `Fecha PlazoDev = fechaPrestamo.obtenerPlazoDev();`

`fechaPrestamo` es una variable de tipo Fecha(dia,mes,año) y lo que quiero hacer en `estaAtrasado` es obtener el Plazo de Devolucion que se definio mas arriba y poder comparar con lo que seria la Fecha de hoy y si la Fecha de hoy es superior al plazo de devolucion entonces retorna true porque esta atrasado

Ahi puse el codigo completo como me lo pediste

```
     class Prestamo{
    
    //atributos de instancia
    
    private Libro libro;
    private String socio;
    private Fecha fechaPrestamo;
    private int dias;
    private Fecha fechaDevolucion;
    
    // constructor
    
    public Prestamo(Libro l, Fecha fp, int d, String s){
        this.libro = libro;
        this.fechaPrestamo = fp;
        this.dias = d;
        this.socio = s;
    }
    
    // comandos
    
    public void establecerFechaDev(Fecha fd){
        this.fechaDevolucion = fd;
    }
    
    // consultas
    
    public Libro obtenerLibro(){
        return this.libro;
    }
    public Fecha obtenerFechaPrestamo(){
        return this.fechaPrestamo;
    }
    public Fecha obtenerPlazoDev(){
        Fecha PlazoDev = fechaPrestamo;
        for (int i = dias; i == 0; i--){
        PlazoDev = fechaPrestamo.diaSiguiente();    
        }
        return PlazoDev;
    }
    public Fecha obtenerFechaDev(){
        return this.fechaDevolucion;
    }
    public String obtenerSocio(){
        return this.socio;
    }
    public boolean estaAtrasado(Fecha hoy){
        Fecha PlazoDev = fechaPrestamo.obtenerPlazoDev();
        if (fechaDevolucion == null && hoy.obtenerAnio()>PlazoDev.obtenerAnio() || hoy.obtenerMes()>PlazoDev.obtenerMes() || hoy.obtenerDia() > PlazoDev.obtenerDia())
        return true;
        else return false;
        
    }
    public Prestamo masAntiguo(Prestamo p){
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Puedes compartir el archivo completo? Esa parte del código parece estar bien. Pero debe haber algo que estás haciendo mal y no lo podemos saber sin ver el panorama completo

Comment: Pero no parece estar dentro de esa clase...

Comment: el método obtenerPlazoDev pertenece a la clase Préstamo ,pero el objeto fechaPrestamo es de la clase Fecha,por ende no puede hacer uso de ese metodo   `Fecha PlazoDev = fechaPrestamo.obtenerPlazoDev();`

Comment: solo pon  `Fecha PlazoDev = obtenerPlazoDev();`

Comment: muchas gracias, ahora entendi el por que del error.